# Is it possible to keep the .hg directory in custom location

Tags: repository, mercurial

I want to have a Mercurial repository set, but instead of having the `.hg/` directory under the repository tree, I would love to move it somewhere away (like to other partition) from working copy.

Is it possible to do in such a way?

Answer (score 6):

Since Mercurial 1.3, you can use the [share extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShareExtension) to indirectly do what you want. Start by enabling the extension by adding the following to `~/.hgrc`:

```
[extensions]
share =
```

Then create a normal repository on the partition where you want the `.hg` directory to be:

```
$ cd /mnt/bigdisk
$ hg init foo
```

Go to the place where you want the working copy to be and create a shared repository:

```
$ cd ~/src
$ hg share /mnt/bigdisk/foo
```

This creates a `~/src/foo` repository for you. This repository will reference the `/mnt/bigdisk/foo` repository. There will still be a `.hg` folder in `~/src/foo`, but it will be almost empty and thus very small. You operate on the shared repository like normal, but all commits go directly to the `/mnt/bigdisk/foo` repository.

The share extension works on all platforms where Mercurial runs (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, ...) since the "symlink" is done internally by Mercurial, not via the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do exactly what you want.  The closest would be to have a symlink `.hg` pointing to the real one.  Please see [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/version-control.mercurial.general/2008-01/msg00306.html).